# fsck in recovery mode does not work

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fsck

When I run fsck in recovery mode, it says that sda3 is mounted.

> /dev/sda3 is mounted
>
> e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting.

However, when I try to umount sda3, it is busy.

> umount: /: target is busy.

How can I clean my filesystem?

Comment: Are you running LVM?  If you are you might want to see https://askubuntu.com/a/1125166/231142

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately with newer systems, using e.g. systemd, the other solutions don't work. I tried the same and entering recovery mode selecting fsck itself, the thing made for this, doesn't do anything.
What you can do is use kernel boot parameters.
For a one go, startup scan you can do:

1. When starting up the system, right after bios test ends, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to enter the grub menu.
2. Then select a menu entry (you can go to advanced and recovery to follow things better) and push <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot entry for this boot only.
3. Go to the `linux ...` line and add the following at the end:
   `fsck.mode=force`. This forces the check. You can also add `fsck.repair=yes` to force repair. By default, only repairs that do not alter integrity of existing and do not cause data loss (eg. orphans are not deleted) will be applied.
4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot

   - An alternative to number 3, and to be more flexible and interactive, instead of adding `fsck..` you can add `break` to the Linux boot line. This should break the boot process at a busybox command prompt and allow you to run fsck with unmounted file systems.

This guide assumes you have grub 2 and Linux kernel 4.13 or newer (tested there)

Maybe a little late but can help others.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 with lvm and kernel 5.3.0-46, `fsck.mode=force` does nothing
with `break`, I got stuck at a blank background

Comment: Well, as written in my answer, `break` is an alternative to `fsck.mode=force`. It stops the boot process, thus the system will do not boot. However, the `busybox` prompt allows you to fsck the system via command line, manually