# Problem with fsck after a blackout (power outage)

Tags: filesystems, manjaro, fsck

Yesterday there was a power outage at my house and, after rebooting my personal computer, the following message was displayed:

```
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Error reading block 152568463 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
```

After this, I tried inputting `fsck/dev/sda2`, which I thought was going to work, [as found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528612/fsck-in-recovery-mode-does-not-work), but, apparently, nothing happened, even after leaving the pc turned on for the entire night, I didn't get a single message back (image below).

If it's useful in any way, I'm using the most recent version of Manjaro (KDE) and my laptop is quite old, about 10 years old.

Also, I'm pretty new to Linux, it hasn't even been two months since I started using it, Manjaro being my first distro, so I'd be most grateful for explicit answers.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there's a shell prompt available in the screenshot: in this case whatever is typed wouldn't be run at all. You should try booting from a live/rescue image to run fsck.

Comment: @A.B would you please specify on how I could do that? Or, maybe, link me to an article or video that might help?

Comment: https://manjaro.org/support/firststeps/ talks about making a Manjaro Live-Environment / Live-System. quoting the end: "Those “Live-Enviroments” are completely functional systems and can be used as portable operating-system or to rescue data if something went wrong."

Comment: @A.B I forgot to say that I just reinstalled my OS and everything has been working fine now. Of course, I lost all my stuff but, fortunately, there wasn't a lot that I had saved, I only lost a few images and videos. Still appreciate the answer though :)